# Determine the elements of a triangle knowing relationships between lengths and angles

Tags: trigonometry

A triangle's sides' lengths are three successive numbers (meaning b=a+1, c=a+2). The smallest angle is a half of the triangle's biggest angle.
Find the area of this triangle and its angles.

Solution:

Sides are 4, 5 and 6.

Area: $15\sqrt{7}/4$

Angles : $41° 24' 34"$ and $82°49'8"$

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. What is your problem with the problem? You've stated the problem, but I don't know what your issue is with it. What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried listing what I have using a^2=b^2+c^2-2*b*c*cosL, but end up needing L to proceed

Comment: This is a really cool problem! You should have said "twice as small" instead of "twice as smaller".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the law of sines,

\begin{align}
   \dfrac{\sin \theta}{a} &= \dfrac{\sin 2\theta}{a+2} \\
   \dfrac{\sin \theta}{a} &= \dfrac{2 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta)}{a+2} \\
   \cos \theta &= \dfrac{a+2}{2a} \\
\end{align}

Using the law of cosines,

\begin{align}
   a^2 &= (a+1)^2 +(a+2)^2 - 2(a+1)(a+2) \cos \theta \\
   \cos \theta &= \dfrac{(a+1)^2 +(a+2)^2 - a^2}{2(a+1)(a+2)} \\
   \cos \theta &= \dfrac{a^2+6a+5}{2(a+1)(a+2)} \\
   \cos \theta &= \dfrac{(a+1)(a+5)}{2(a+1)(a+2)} \\
   \cos \theta &= \dfrac{a+5}{2(a+2)} \\
\hline
   \dfrac{a+2}{2a} &= \dfrac{a+5}{2(a+2)} \\
   \dfrac{a+2}{a} &= \dfrac{a+5}{a+2} \\
   1 + \dfrac 2a &= 1 + \dfrac{3}{a+2} \\
   \dfrac 2a &= \dfrac{3}{a+2} \\
   3a &= 2a + 4 \\
   a &= 4
\end{align}

CHECKING

$a=4$

Smallest angle is $\theta$:

$\qquad \cos \theta = \dfrac{a+2}{2a} = \dfrac 34$

$\qquad \sin \theta = \dfrac{\sqrt 7}{4}$

$\qquad \theta \approx 41.41^\circ$

The 'middle' angle is $180^\circ - 3\theta$

$\qquad \cos(180^\circ - 3\theta) = -\cos 3\theta = \dfrac {9}{16}$

$\qquad \sin(180^\circ - 3\theta) = \sin 3\theta = \dfrac {5\sqrt 7}{16}$

$\qquad 180^\circ - 3\theta \approx 55.77^\circ$

Largest angle is $2 \theta$:

$\qquad \sin 2\theta
  = 2 \; \sin \theta \; \cos \theta
  = \dfrac{3 \sqrt 7}{8}$

$\qquad \cos 2\theta 
  = 2\cos^2 \theta - 1
  = \dfrac 18$

$\qquad  2\theta \approx 82.82^\circ$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:

Solve

$$\frac{\sin\theta}{a}=\frac{\sin3\theta}{a+1}=\frac{\sin2\theta}{a+2}.$$

---

> $$\frac{\sin\theta}a=\frac{4\sin\theta\cos^2\theta-\sin\theta}{a+1}=\frac{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{a+2}\implies\frac1a=\frac{4\cos^2\theta-1}{a+1}=\frac{2\cos\theta}{a+2}\\\implies a^2-3a-4=0\implies a=4$$ by eliminating $\cos\theta$. Next, $\cos\theta=3/4$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the "$\sin(3 \theta)$".

Comment: @JeanMarie I am not giving the full solution. OP needs to figure out. But $\theta=30°$ is certainly not implied.

Comment: @JeanMarie - actually it's $\sin(180^\circ - 3\theta)$ which just happens to equal $\sin 3\theta$.The angles are $\theta, 2\theta$ and $180^\circ - 3\theta$.

Comment: @JeanMarie: I didn't write that the third angle is $3\theta$, did I?

Comment: @Steven Gregory Thanks, it's clear now.

Comment: @JeanMarie In either case, it's not necessary to solve the problem any way.

Comment: @Yves Daoust it's clear now.

Comment: @Steven Gregory What do you mean ?

Comment: Neat solution [+1]